# logger -s prints <13> in Ubuntu 16 LTS

Tags: 16.04, logging

In former LTS releases, the `logger -s` command just printed the text to stderr:
Ubuntu 14 LTS (`package bsdutils, current version 1:2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.9`) and
Ubuntu 12 LTS (`package bsdutils, current version 1:2.20.1-1ubuntu3.1`):

```
logger -s -t test text
test: text
```

But in the current LTS release, it prepends some strange text:
Ubuntu 16 LTS (`package bsdutils, current version 1:2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3`):

```
logger -s -t test text
<13>Aug 24 12:19:04 test: text
```

I understand that there has been a date prepended in the new version.
But what does `<13>` mean ?
(The `syslog` itself does not contain that `<13>` string.)

Edit: Bonus question: How can I get rid of that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value <13> is *the priority prefix* for priority `user.notice`

Example for various priority values:

```
$ logger -p user.error -s -t test text 
<11>Aug 24 13:55:08 test: text
$ logger -p user.warn -s -t test text 
<12>Aug 24 13:55:02 test: text
$ logger -p user.notice -s -t test text 
<13>Aug 24 13:54:55 test: text
$ logger -p user.info -s -t test text 
<14>Aug 24 13:54:59 test: text

$ logger -p local0.error -s -t test text 
<131>Aug 24 13:58:52 test: text
```

[man logger](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html)

> -p, --priority
> priority Enter the message into the log with the
> specified priority. The priority may be specified numerically or as a
> facility.level pair.  For example, -p local3.info logs the message as
> informational in the local3 facility.  **The default is user.notice.**
>
> --prio-prefix
> Look for a syslog prefix on every line read from standard input.  **This prefix is a decimal number within angle brackets
> that encodes both the facility and the level.  The number is
> constructed by multiplying the facility by 8 and then adding the
> level.  For example, local0.info, meaning facility=16 and level=6,
> becomes <134>.**
> If the prefix contains no facility, the facility defaults to what is specified by the -p option.  Similarly, if no prefix is provided,
> the line is logged using the priority given with -p.

Comment: My version of `man logger` contains some more text for the `--prio-prefix` option: `This option doesn't affect a command-line message.` And I have a command-line message here, or don't I ?

Comment: @Juergen - I've quote the man for `--prio-prefix` for the completeness of the calculation example.

Comment: Thank you. Seems the prio-prefix is prepended whether or not the `--prio-prefix` option is used and cannot be removed. Or can I suppress that ?